# Is it possible to use the search API to lookup many tags at the same time?

Tags: support, search, api

I am currently using

`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&site=stackoverflow&accepted=False&sort=activity&tagged=MY_TAG`
in order to query all unanswered questions marked with `MY_TAG`.

Is it possible to do the same thing with multiple tags at the same time?
From my understanding the API allows you to find questions that have all the tags specified at the same time by just separating them with `;` (or a logical `AND` if you may). I would to like to find questions that might contain at least one of the specified tags (a logical `OR`)

Would I have to perform multiple queries in order to get what I need?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, the only separator allowed afaik is semicolon, and it performs the "AND" search - so probably you'll have to send two requests and join it by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `q` parameter and treat it as you would treat a search box in any SE site, which means you can use the operator `OR` between two [tags]. For example:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?
order=desc&site=stackoverflow&accepted=False&sort=activity&q=[tag1] OR [tag2]
```

Comment: That seems to work. Cheers 